# SQL Management Studio 2012 with Excel vba connection string set up

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I would like to set up a vba code that would connect to sql management studio 2012 a run the query, which I would specify in the vba code. I have read every similar question here on stack overflow but when I try to replicate them, I always get an error, ussualy that the login failed for user.

I think I am setting up the string connection wrong. Also, I would need the user authentication by Windows authentication.

I know the database name, server name and my user name.

This is the code I am using and which is giving me an error.

```
Sub ConnectionExample6()
 Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

 Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

 ' Open a connection by referencing the ODBC driver.
 cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
  "server=SERVER NAME;uid=USER ID;pwd=MyPassword;database=DATABASE NAME"
 cnn.Open

' Create a Recordset by executing an SQL statement.
 Set rs = cnn.Execute("Select top 100 * from "TABLE NAME" aac " & _
 "where aac.EffectiveDate = '10/04/16'")

 ' Close the connection.
 rs.Close

End Sub
```

Can someone walk me through the connection string and how to set it up step by step? Thank you.

Comment: the error is: Run-time error '-2147217843 (80040e4d)':[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login failed for user 'USER ID'

Comment: If you want to use Windows Authentication, don't provide a user ID / password in the connection string.

Comment: Mat nailed it, just make sure all users who will use this macro have public access to the SQL server and database. Or, add them to a group on the domain which has access.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, it works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Authentication

If you're connecting to SQL Server, you should prefer Windows Authentication if that's available: you create a *Login* at server level for a group of Active Directory users, and then you create a Windows-Authenticated *User* in your database using that login.

That way you are keeping passwords and usernames out of hard-coded strings, and let the network deal with authentication.

Assuming you don't want to be maintaining passwords in dozens of copies of macro-enabled workbooks across your network, you'll want to use Windows Authentication.

```xml
Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=True;
```

---

#### Server

Connection strings *are* annoying - seems there's a different format/wording for every single different thing that's able to parse them!

Since you're using ADODB, you'll want to specify a *Provider*, a *Data Source* and, optionally, an *Initial Catalog*:

```xml
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Data Source=SQL Server instance name; Initial Catalog=Database name;
```

---

#### Who?

Each connection can be monitored on the server; when building your connection string you can optionally specify a *Workstation ID* to identify the machine the connection is for.

```xml
Workstation ID=computer name;
```

You can get the computer name by fetching the environment variable value, using `Environ$`:

```vb
Private Function GetWorkstationId() As String
    GetWorkstationId = Environ$("ComputerName")
End Function
```

---

Given a SQL Server instance named `SomeSqlServer`, a database named `SomeDatabase`, and using Windows Authentication, the ADODB connection string would look like this:

```vb
Dim connString As String
connString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Data Source=SomeSqlServer; Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase; Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=True;"
```

Given SQL Authentication (with a hard-coded user name and password) for `SomeUser` with `SomePassword`:

```vb
connString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Data Source=SomeSqlServer; Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase; UID=SomeUser; PWD=SomePassword;"
```

---

#### Commands

You don't want to be concatenating arbitrary user input into a WHERE clause; avoid executing an SQL string directly from the `ADODB.Connection` object.

Instead, create an `ADODB.Command`, and *parameterize* your query.

```vb
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT Foo, Bar FROM dbo.FooBars WHERE Foo = ? AND DateInserted > ?"
```

Here we have 2 parameters.

First we create the *command*:

```vb
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = sql
```

Then its parameters, assuming we have their respective values in `param1Value` and `param2Value` local variables:

```vb
Dim param1 As ADODB.Parameter ' a string parameter
Set param1 = New ADODB.Parameter
param1.Type = adVarWChar
param1.Direction = adParamInput
param1.Size = Len(param1Value)
param1.Value = param1Value
cmd.Parameters.Append param1

Dim param2 As ADODB.Parameter ' a date parameter
Set param2 = New ADODB.Parameter
param2.Type = adDate
param2.Direction = adParamInput
param2.Value = param2Value
cmd.Parameters.Append param2
```

Then we retrieve the recordset by executing the command:

```vb
Dim results As ADODB.Recordset
Set results = cmd.Execute
```

Of course this looks very verbose, but it can easily be refactored into functions dedicated to creating a parameter given a value of a certain type.

As a result, you avoid this situation, because you're no longer executing arbitrary user input concatenated into a query:

[image: XKCD: Exploits of a Mom]

Comment: Great answer, better cartoon